# Fallo al conectar Base de datos de Heroku a Aplicación de PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, heroku

No logro comunicar la base de datos creada en Heroku con la aplicación que cree en PHP. Es primera vez que uso Heroku así que quizás sea un error tonto. Uso pg_pconnect como lo dice el manual de PHP para conectarse a postgressql. Leí a alguien en ingles que le pasa algo similar pero no vi que le dieran solución, este es el código de la conexión que use:

```php
$host = "ec2-54-235-242-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
$usuario = "usuario";
$password = "pass";
$database = "dbname";
$port = "5432";
    
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=".$host." port=".$port
              ." dbname=".$database." user=".$username." password=".$password)
    or die('No me puedo Conectar: ' . pg_last_error());
```

Aparentemente el error puede estar en alguna de estas partes del código:

```php
include('conexion.php');
if (isset($_POST['salvar_tarea'])) {
   $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
   $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
   echo $titulo. '<br>';
   echo $descripcion. '<br>';
   $insercion = "INSERT INTO Tareas (titulo, descripcion) VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion')";
   $resultado = pg_query($conexion, $insercion);
   if ($conexion -> query($insercion) === true) {
      //echo 'Exito <br>';
      $_SESSION['message'] = 'Tarea Guardada';
      $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
      header('location: index.php');
      } else {
    echo 'Error <br>';
     }
     }
```

O aquí:

```php
<?php 
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM Tareas";
$resultado = pg_query($conexion, $consulta);
while ($fila = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $fila['titulo']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['descripcion']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['fecha']; ?></td>
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-marker"></i></a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
?>
```

Al menos eso señala la consola.

Comment: https://gestortareasapp.herokuapp.com/ esa es la app, no guarda las tareas.

Comment: ¿Qué errores te muestra tu `error_logs` dentro de tu servidor Heroku?

Comment: El error es TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, resource given in /app/save.php:9

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca esa parte de tu archivo `app/save.php` que te da el error por favor. El error es de **mysqli** pero estas usando **postgreSQL**, hay algo mal allí

Comment: Creo que tu error esta aquí `if ($conexion -> query($insercion) === true) { ...` no tengo muchos conocimientos de la extensión de **postgreSQL** pero creo que solo proporciona funciones estáticas y estas usando una sintaxis parecida a la orientada a objetos de **mysqli**, deberías hacer algo como `if ($resultado) { ...`

Comment: Aunque viéndolo bien ¿tu conexión no es `$dbconn`? ¿que seria entonces `$conexion`?

Comment: @Josbert es acertado lo que dices, le cambie por if ($resultado) y ahora me sale error, pero no se cual es el error ahora, el pg_query($conexion, $consulta); no inserta los dats a la tabla supongo.

Comment: Como te comentaba, ¿de que se trata `$conexion`, acaso tu conexión no era `$dbconn`? por cierto el error creo que lo puedes ver igual en el **log de heroku**